# Xamarin Android lost data after re-opening app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, io, xamarin.android

I have created an application that has save / load functions (personal data etc.). When the application is running, saving and loading data works well. Unfortunately, after re-opening the application stored data disappear and when I try to open files, i have a null reference exception. In settings (tools->option->xamarin) I checked "Preserve application data/cache on device between deploys". Below are my I/O functions:

```
public void SerializeObject(T obj)
    {            
        string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "data.txt");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, jsonData);
    }
    public T DeSerializeObject()
    {
        var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "data.txt");
        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        T obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(text);
        return obj;
    }
```

**edit:** Below is Button.click functions which save data.

```
 private void saveButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        _data.x = this.x;
        _data.y = this.y;
        _data.z = this.z;
        IOoperation<Data> save = new IOoperation<Data>();
        save.SerializeObject(_data);
        TextView _current = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.currentPositionTextView);
        _current.Text = string.Format("Saved position: {0}, {1}, {2}", _data.x, _data.y, _data.z);
    }

    private void loadButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IOoperation<Data> load = new IOoperation<Data>();            
        Data obj = load.DeSerializeObject();

        TextView _current = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.currentPositionTextView);
        _current.Text = string.Format("Saved position: {0}, {1}, {2} - loaded", _data.x, _data.y, _data.z);
    }
```

Comment: Using System.IO.File.WriteAllText will create a new file with only the new entry available when you try to DeSerialize the object. Under this scenario there would only ever be one entry. Are you potentially overwriting what you expected to be there or expecting deserialize to return multiple entries? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue, I have create a [demo](https://github.com/mikexxma/SpecialFolder.Personal_Demo.git) with your code, it works fine when I reopen the app.

Comment: I want to simple overwriting my file with new data. @MikeMa I edited my post and there is an additional the code. Maybe there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue:

`_current.Text = string.Format("Saved position: {0}, {1}, {2} - loaded", _data.x, _data.y, _data.z);`

When you reopen the app `_data` is `null` please use `obj` to get the data :

`_current.Text = string.Format("Saved position: {0}, {1}, {2} - loaded", obj.x, obj.y, obj.z);`